# Javascript - cannot get login script to only accept set password

Tags: javascript, authentication, passwords

I am trying to make a basic login screen using Javascript, in which I don't have much experience. I managed to get this much, but for some reason, whenever I enter text into the input box it will redirect me, no matter whether it is the correct password or not.

Also, a second question, to determine whether or not a user has logged in (to redirect them to the login page), would I have to use something other than JS, such as PHP?

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function login()
                {
                if (password = "cat")
                    {
                    location.assign("home.html");
                    }
                }
        </script>     
    </head>
    <body>
        Password: <input type = "password" name = "password">
        <input type = "button" value = "Login" onclick = "login()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked by many before. The code needs to use an Ajax request to the server.

Also , you do need a server side language to do the validation . Something like below, example is using Jquery library

HTML

```
<body>
 <?php session_start(); ?>
<div id="profile">
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
?>
<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>
<?php }else {?>
<a id="login_a" href="#">login</a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="login_form">
<div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
<form action="login.php">
<label>User Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" />
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
<label></label><br/>
<input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" />
<input type="button" id="cancel_hide" value="Cancel" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="shadow" class="popup"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login_a").click(function(){
$("#shadow").fadeIn("normal");
$("#login_form").fadeIn("normal");
$("#user_name").focus();
});
$("#cancel_hide").click(function(){
$("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
$("#shadow").fadeOut();
});
$("#login").click(function(){

username=$("#user_name").val();
password=$("#password").val();
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "login.php",
 data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
 success: function(html){
 if(html=='true')
 {
 $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
 $("#shadow").fadeOut();
 $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>");

 }
 else
 {
 $("#add_err").html("Wrong username or password");
 }
},
 beforeSend:function()
 {
 $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
 }
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

PHP code

```
 <?php
  session_start();
 $username = $_POST['name'];
 $password = md5($_POST['pwd']);
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
 $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 if( $num_row >=1 ) {
  echo 'true';
  $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
 }
 else{
 echo 'false';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use Python for this because I have some experience in it. There is an OAuth binding for Python, which I will be using.

Answer (score 2):

currently you are using `if(password = "cat")` which is actually an assignment operator not used for `comparison`. If you don't know the type of data to be compared use `==` otherwise you can use `===`.

In otherword

- `==` is used to compare the values only.
- `===` is used to compare the values as well as type.

Check like this

```
if(password === "cat")
```

And for your another query if you want to make a web app or something. You should use server side interaction using `PHP or WPF or any other like JSON` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is really the wrong way to implement login. Any password checking has to happen on the server, because otherwise the password will be visible on the client, and it will be trivial for users to see the required password. Furthermore, please, please, please, please do not create yet another username/password login... this is what [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) is intended to solve; let the identity experts handle login, and simply delegate to another identity provider.

That being said, the error in your code is that you use a single equals sign ("=") which performs assignment, whereas you really intend to use the double equals ("==") or triple equals ("===") for comparison.